# how to create a list after a while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have a question about how to create a list after the while loop. I want to put all the numbers I get from while loop into a list
for example:

```
x=4
while(1):
    print(x)
    x=x+1
    if x==8:break
```

then I get

```
4
5
6
7
```

I want to show these numbers in one list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the append() function. Check out the [python lists document here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) for more information.

```
list=[] #declare a blank list to use later
x=4

while(1):
    list.append(x) #add x to the list
    x += 1 # a shorthand way to add 1 to x
    if x == 8:break

print(list) #after the loop is finished, print the list
```

Answer (score 2):

```
l=[]
x=4

while(1):
    print(x)
    l.append(x)

    x=x+1
    if x==8:break

print(l)
```

That's how you'd add it to your code. FYI, if you want to do it the "Pythonic" way, it's as simple as:

```
l = range(4, 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
L = []
i = 4
while i<=8:
    print(i)
    L.append(i)
    i += 1
```